# Forbidding insertion of integer not in rowid in SQLite (keep directed acyclic graph table consistent)

Tags: database, sqlite, directed-acyclic-graphs, consistency, referential-integrity

I'd like to express:

"insertion of record with 'parent' value that is not included in 'rowid' AFTER INSERTION is forbidden."

My intention is to keep the table internally consistent as a directed acyclic graph, with every record being a node referring to its parent (root nodes are their own parent). How can I do that?

Here's what I have (with rowid used as the primary key):

```
CREATE TABLE Heap (                                                                                                       
                   name   TEXT     CHECK(typeof(name) = 'text')                                                           
                                   NOT NULL                                                                               
                                   UNIQUE                      ,                                       
                   parent INTEGER  DEFAULT rowid               ,                                       
                   color  INTEGER  CHECK(color BETWEEN 0 AND 2)                                                           
                  );                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                      
CREATE TRIGGER parent_not_in_rowid                                                                                        
BEFORE INSERT ON Heap                                                                                                     
BEGIN                                                                                                                     
 SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'parent id inconsistent') FROM Heap                                                                   
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Heap WHERE NEW.rowid = NEW.parent);                                                       
END;
```

Comment: `NEW.rowid` is undefined in a BEFORE INSERT trigger. Why don't you set `parent` to `null` for root nodes?

Comment: @forpas yes, I'm thinking that perhaps the right way to go would be to wrap an `insert` query inside a transaction and rollback if consistency is not maintained? I could use `null` for roots, but does that not add some overhead due to the need to handle `null` separately when traversing the graph?

Comment: I don't know how you plan to traverse the graph and if null adds any overhead, but if you use null then all you need is referential integrity and no triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `null` values in the column `parent` for root nodes, because this way all you have to do is add referential integrity to your table.

Add a column `id` defined as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, so that it is an alias of the `rowid` and also make the column `parent` to reference `id`:

```
CREATE TABLE Heap ( 
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(typeof(name) = 'text'),
  parent INTEGER REFERENCES Heap(id),                                       
  color INTEGER CHECK(color BETWEEN 0 AND 2)                                                           
);
```

Now, turn on foreign key support:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

and insert rows:

```
INSERT INTO Heap (name, parent, color) VALUES ('name1', null, 1);
INSERT INTO Heap (name, parent, color) VALUES ('name2', 1, 1);
```

This will fail:

```
INSERT INTO Heap (name, parent, color) VALUES ('name3', 5, 2);
```

because there is no row in the table with `id = 5`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ff3f56621af2ed5bf664523610f86502).